# CUDA & Copy-constructor

Tags: c++, object, cuda, copy-constructor

I've been struggling with an issue in CUDA. I've written a recursive kernel (allowed in the latest). The .cu file is part of a big project with a number of objects.
One of the parameters of the kernel is a Piece object ( Piece.cpp ) like this:

```
parallelKernel (Piece* piece, vector upcomingPieces)
```

When I need to get the recursive call, I build up the next piece index, so I wrote something like this:

```
Piece *nextPiece = upcomingPieces[nextPieceIndex];
parallelKernel (nextPiece, upcomingPieces);
```

but I get an error at compile-time:

```
error: cannot pass an argument with a user-provided copy-constructor to a device-side kernel launch
```

Now, I have been trying to write a copy-constructor, but I can't seem to get it right. Can anyone provide more insight about this??

Comment: The problem is though that a user provided copy ctr exists, and probably that one shouldn't exist for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

CUDA cannot really support certain C++ constructs, mostly around constructors (as well as copy-constructors) for global/shared memory. The problem is - who would execute the constructor? All threads? Just one thread? Every thread for himself?

For example these are invalid:

```
__shared__ int x = 0;
__shared__ MyClassWithNontrivialConstructor obj;
```

I guess you are hitting a similar problem.

Is by any chance `upcomingPieces` lying somewhere in shared or global memory?
If that is the case - consider passing the parameter through const-reference or by a pointer.